HubSpot - Mendix embedding iframe issues
I am having issues with an iframe (which holds the URL to a Mendix app) that is on my HubSpot website. Upon loading my webpage, the page automatically scrolls down to the iframe. Originally I suspected that this was an iframe/HubSpot theme issue, but when I swapped the URL to another website that I had developed (not a Mendix app), it did not do the automatic scroll. It may be worth noting that the page that the URL points to does load via microflow and creates and an object. However, this has always been the case and this scroll was never an issue. it may also be worth noting that my app was originally developed via Mendix 9.22 and I recently upgraded it to Mendix 10.9. This is a huge issue as this page is live for our customers to see. Does anyone have any idea on how this can be fixed?
You can visit my test webpage to see the scroll at stellarone.io/health-beauty
my iframe code is:
<iframe  id="Pricing Calc"
title="Pricing Calc"
width="1500"
height="1300"
frameBorder="0" src="https://portal.stellar1cloud.com/p/eCommerce"
>
</iframe>

